Sample weights for loss computing by huggingface transformer model
I'm training a GPT2LMHeadModel in Python using huggingface's transformers library. The task is next token prediction. If I understand correctly, if this object is provided a labels argument, it should automatically compute loss for each pair of tokens, i.e. if I have input [1,2,3], then the object should compute the loss for each of the (input, next_token) combinations: ([1], [2]) and ([1,2], [3])
My dataset includes weights for each sample. Is there a way for me to include these weights in the training process? Note that these are not class weights, but weights for each individual record in my train set. In a more "vanilla" training scenario with PyTroch, I would just set reduction='none' on my criterion, then multiple the result by the batch's weights. I'm not sure how I would implement this efficiently, accounting for all the prediction tasks that go into a single sequence.

I've found something that may work, but would appreciate someone's verification. Since the logits of a GPT2LMHeadModel have shape (batch_size, sequence_length, vocab_size), I did the following:
criterion = CrossEntropyLoss(reduction=False)
logits = model(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask).logits

# Shift input IDs left by 1 position
labels = input_ids.roll(-1, dims=1)[:, :-1]

# Reshape logits to (N, C, ...) as required by CrossEntropyLoss 
logits_reshape = logits[:, :-1, :].transpose(1,2)

# Output has dim (batch_size, sequence_length). Take mean along sequence_length
loss = criterion(logits_reshape, labels).mean(axis=1) 

loss *= weights
loss = loss.mean()

